# polyline heading Google Maps api v2 Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I'm having some difficulty with this polyline. I've use the computeHeading method in the spherical utils library in combination with the location of two points to generate a third point and make a line in that direction with the computeOffset. My goal is to have the line point in the direction that I am moving. Currently instead of pointing to the present heading The far end stays stationary and the near end  moves with the blue tracker.

```
public static LatLng point1, point2, point3 ;
public static LatLng navOrigin;
public static LatLng navSecPoint;
public static Polyline navigationalLine;
```

I create the polyline and delete the old one with:

```
 public void navPointer() { 

    PolylineOptions navigation = new PolylineOptions()
    .add(navOrigin)
    .add(navSecPoint)
    .color(Color.MAGENTA);

    if(navigationalLine !=null) { navigationalLine.remove(); }
    else { navigationalLine = getMap().addPolyline(navigation); }

    navigationalLine.remove();

     navigationalLine = getMap().addPolyline(navigation);

}
```

I then use the onLocationChanged to collect my points and calculate the heading and then execute the navPointer():

```
@Override
public void  onLocationChanged(Location location) {



    point1 = (new LatLng(location.getLatitude()   , location.getLongitude()));

    point2 = (new LatLng(location.getLatitude()   , location.getLongitude()));

     heading = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(point1, point2);

     navOrigin = (new LatLng(location.getLatitude()   , location.getLongitude()));

     navSecPoint = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(point2, 500, heading);

    navPointer();

}
```

IGNORE the Map Markers

Again, no matter where I walk the far end doesn't move, but the near end of the polyline tracks the blue tracker marker.

[image]