# onLocationChanged in time increments

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using onLocationChanged to:

```
    //set the location of a point
    point1 = (new LatLng(location.getLatitude()   , location.getLongitude()));
```

I'm trying to construct a polyline that points in the direction of the heading as I'm moving. Ive used the computeHeading method to calculate the heading and then I put that in computeOffset to generate another point x feet away as the far point to generate a polyline. This is done like this:

```
@Override
public void  onLocationChanged(Location location) {




    point1 = (new LatLng(location.getLatitude()   , location.getLongitude()));



    point2 = (new LatLng(location.getLatitude()   , location.getLongitude()));

     heading = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(point1, point2);

     navOrigin = (new LatLng(location.getLatitude()   , location.getLongitude()));

     navSecPoint = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(point2, 500, heading);



     PolylineOptions navigation = new PolylineOptions()
        .add(navOrigin)
        .add(navSecPoint)
        .color(Color.MAGENTA);

        if(navigationalLine !=null) { navigationalLine.remove(); }
        else { navigationalLine = getMap().addPolyline(navigation); }


         navigationalLine = getMap().addPolyline(navigation);
```

Only problem is to determine an instantaneous heading I need a distinct location for point1 and for point2. Currently as they are both in my onLocationChanged they both fill with the same location data. You can't compute a heading if both points are in the same spot.

How do I create some sort of timer or location based firing mechanism that gives some millisecond time delay between when point1 is filled with location data and a couple feet later to fill point2 with location data.

[You can see the problem illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22546953/polyline-heading-google-maps-api-v2-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a timer to offset the location of two points is not necessary. Although a heading could be calculated with the spherical util tools the android.location series has a getBearing() method that continually updates with the heading of the device.

The

```
navSecPoint = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(point2, 500, heading);
```

could be substituted with:

```
navSecPoint = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(point2, 500, bearing);
```

the getBearing() method is a float and the computeOffset requires a double. This can be done:

```
float floatbearing = location.getBearing();

    double bearing = floatbearing;
```

If you did decide to use a timer. Use the java.util.TimerTask.

Follow this tutorial:

[run() with Timer](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/12/example-of-using-timer-and-timertask-on.html)